# NoMethodError for time_zone_select in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activesupport

I've set up my app exactly in line with the [Railscasts Time Zone Episode 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-in-rails-2-1) but when I run

```
<%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones %>
```

I get this error

> NoMethodError in Users#new
>
> Showing app/views/users/new.html.erb
>   where line #27 raised:
>
> You have a nil object when you didn't
>   expect it! You might have expected an
>   instance of Array. The error occurred
>   while evaluating nil.<=>

With line 27 being the aforementioned line.  I am really stuck on this...

Comment: can you check what `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones` gives in console?

Comment: [#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x7112460 @utc_offset=-36000, @current_period=nil, @name="Hawaii".... and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem. It seems to be related to Rails 2.3.8, because if I revert back to my previous version (2.3.4, by setting this in the /config/environment.rb), everything works fine. Looks like a bug. I'm checking out whether this bug report and resulting patch will solve this issue: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/4942-activesupporttimezone-incorrectly-stores-bogus-values-in-zones_map#ticket-4942 .

Comment: I do actually think this is a bug as well.  I really can't even remember what I did to fix this but I eventually did. I was working with a locally seeded database so I ended up dropping, creating, and migrating it.  I'm not sure if that's what it was, but it's worth a try if you can afford to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a database field for that model named time_zone? is it named timezone instead?

You'd need a migration with something like:

```
add_column :users, :time_zone, :string
```

then

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I ran in to a problem here because of a spelling mistake between the database/migration and the view, so check for typos, if that wasn't obvious.

Can you include a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bug in 2.3.8, and it's been fixed in the aforementioned ticket.

It was probably caused by a stored time zone in a database field that didn't correspond to any time zone either Rails or TZInfo knew about. In our case, it was tripped by accidentally HTML encoding ampersands, so that `Pacific Time (US & Canada)` became `Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)`. http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/78e4d88c7071c633ee1eb68f49b90719aa198eaa should resolve it, but you might want to go back and make sure you don't still have any bad data in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, which caused one of my Cucumber tests to fail.  I upgraded to Rails 2.3.9 (from 2.3.8) and all tests passed.  Good luck!